# WebSocketChannel becomes null when passed to a StatefulWidget's State class

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, flutter-web

I have a simple client code in which I'm trying to pass the WebSocketChannel instance to an inner stateful widget, and for some reason when I try to run the code the app crushes and displays on the screen "Unexpected null value. See also: [https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors"](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors%22). It would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain to me why this happens and how to fix it.

The code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final WebSocketChannel channel;

  const TestWidget(this.channel);

  @override
  _TestWidgetState createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  String buttonText = '';

  _TestWidgetState() {
    widget.channel.stream.listen((data){
      setState(() {buttonText = data;}); 
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: (){widget.channel.sink.add('hello');},
      child: Text(buttonText)
    );
  }
}



class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final WebSocketChannel channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://localhost:8000/')
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: 
      TestWidget(channel)
    ));
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please post the error you see when running this app. It would be easier to see which object is actually `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you put

```
final WebSocketChannel channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws://localhost:8000/')
  );
```

in App? Move this line code to TestStateWidget constructor. It's best practice u follow null safety method when try to access an object.